# HBase Coprocessor Row Update Detection

Tags: hbase

How can I detect row update in HBase Coprocessor ?

I am trying to figure it out in postPut() function of RegionObserver but it is invoked in every put request even if value is not changed.

Assume this is sequence of operations:

1. put 'testTable','row2','cf:f1','val1'
2. put 'testTable','row2','cf:f1','val1'
3. put 'testTable','row2','cf:f1','val2'

So, I want to detect when operation 1 and 3 happens i.e. when row is added for first time and when value is changed. Not when same value is pushed again.

Is there any way so that inside postPut() function I can get old value of cell ? And compare it with new value.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in pre-put and lookup the record in the coprocessor region.  If the record is new, it should not perform physical I/O since the bloom filter will be correct 99% of the time.

We have a few optimizations at Splice Machine (Open Source) where we access the bloom filter directly to get around the synchronization in the scan.  You can checkout our github site https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine and search for this class and method HRegionUtil.keyExists().

Good luck.

Comment: But, doing it in prePut() will bring down the performance of HBase since I am doing a heavy task after detection of these updates.